# write list of paragraph tuples to a csv file

Tags: python, csv

The following code is designed to write a tuple, each containing a large paragraph of text, and 2 identifiers behind them, to a single line per each entry.

```
import urllib2
import json
import csv

base_url = "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?page={}
writer = csv.writer(open("./data/events.csv", "a"))
writer.writerow(["description", "category_id", "subcategory_id"])

def format_event(event):
    return event["description"]["text"].encode("utf-8").rstrip("\n\r"), event["category_id"], event["subcategory_id"]

for x in range(1, 2):
    print "fetching page - {}".format(x)
    formatted_url = base_url.format(str(x))
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(formatted_url)
    data = resp.read()
    j_data = json.loads(data)
    events = map(format_event, j_data["events"])
    for event in events:
        #print event
        writer.writerow(event)

    print "wrote out events for page - {}".format(x)
```

The ideal format would be to have each line contain a single paragraph, followed by the other fields listed above, yet here is a screenshot of how the data comes out.

[image]

If instead I this line to the following:

```
writer.writerow([event])
```

Here is how the file now looks:
[image]

It certainly looks much closer to what I want, but its got parenthesis around each entry which are undesirable.

**EDIT**
[here](https://gist.github.com/IoDmitri/6bec1ccffa936fe37b3ef72ca6414168) is a snippet that contains a sample of the data Im working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try writing to the CSV file directly without using using the `csv` module? You can write/append comma-delimited strings to the CSV file just like writing to typical text files. Also, the way you deal with removing `\r` and `\n` characters might not be working. You can use regex to find those characters and replace them with an empty string `""`:

```
import urllib2
import json
import re

base_url = "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?page={}"

def format_event(event):
    ws_to_strip = re.compile(r"(\r|\n)")
    description = re.sub(ws_to_strip, "", event["description"]["text"].encode("utf-8"))
    return [description, event["category_id"], event["subcategory_id"]]

with open("./data/events.csv", "a") as events_file:
    events_file.write(",".join(["description", "category_id", "subcategory_id"]))

    for x in range(1, 2):
        print "fetching page - {}".format(x)
        formatted_url = base_url.format(str(x))
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(formatted_url)
        data = resp.read()
        j_data = json.loads(data)
        events = map(format_event, j_data["events"])

        for event in events:
            events_file.write(",".join(event))

        print "wrote out events for page - {}".format(x)
```

Comment: I still have the same problem with spacing, I've added a snippet that has a sample of the data Im working with.

Comment: The problem might be with the way you deal with removing the `\r` and `\n` characters. I have updated my answer to reflect a solution that utilizes regex to find those characters and replace them with an empty string `""`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your csv writer to be [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter).

Make a few tweaks:

```
def format_event(event):
    return {"description": event["description"]["text"].encode("utf-8").rstrip("\n\r"), 
            "category_id": event["category_id"], 
            "subcategory_id": event["subcategory_id"]}
```

May be a few other small things you need to do, but using DictWriter and formatting your data appropriately has been the easiest way to work with csv files that I've found.

Comment: I still have the same problem with spacing, I've added a snippet that has a sample of the data Im working with.

Comment: If I instead turn the dictionary into json and dump it the text is properly formatted though.